# Bootstrap 4 : how to print a column as full-width?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, printing

I have two columns in Bootstrap and I would like to have only the right column printed by the user.

Adding the class "d-print-none" on the left column hide the left column when printing. However, the right column does not stretch to full-width. col-md-8 width still seems to apply to the width of the column.

I have tried to add a class "col-print-12" with no success.

```css
.col-print-12 {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-print-none">
          Sidebar to hide when printing
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-10 col-print-12">
          Main content to print
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just the col class on the second element to auto-fit it:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="border d-none d-md-block col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-print-none">
            Sidebar to hide when printing
        </div>
        <div class="border col">
            Main content to print
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I added the border class to make the elements visible in width)